STM32 freeRTOS program stuck in vPortEnterCritical() while getting data from DHT11
I programmed a freeRTOS on STM32F407
Can use 4x4 matrix keyboard to get data such as temperature and humidity
below code is keyboard task that keep scanning 4x4 matrix keyboard's input. For example the converted value would be 'A', then the program will jump to handle_authenticated_input
static void app_task_keyboard(void *pvParameter)
{
    int8_t key_val = 0;
    char convertion_val;
    uint8_t temp_buf[4];
    int8_t dht11_ret = 0;

    tft_t tft;

    BaseType_t uxHighWaterMark;

    for(;;)
    {
        key_val = matrix_key_scan();

        // dgb_printf_safe("keyboard\r\n");

        // 判断是否输入正确密码进入系统
        if(authenticated)
        {
            // 开始扫描用户按键，执行相应的功能
            if(key_val >0 && key_val < 17)
            {
                convertion_val = matrix_val_convert(key_val);

                dgb_printf_safe("%c\r\n", convertion_val);

                // 通过识别到的按键，进行功能选择
                handle_authenticated_input(convertion_val);
            }
        }

        vTaskDelay(1);
    }
}

code of handle_authenticated_input
void handle_authenticated_input(char input_val)
{
    uint8_t temp_buf[4];
    int8_t dht11_ret = 0;

    switch (input_val)
    {
    case 'A':
        // 温度查询
        dht11_ret = dht11_get_data(temp_buf);
        if(dht11_ret)
        {
            dgb_printf_safe("temp: %02d.%02d\r\n", temp_buf[2], temp_buf[3]);
        }
        else
            dgb_printf_safe("get temp failed:%d\r\n", dht11_ret);
        break;
    case 'B':
        // 湿度查询
        dht11_ret = dht11_get_data(temp_buf);
        if(dht11_ret)
        {
            dgb_printf_safe("humi: %02d.%02d\r\n", temp_buf[0], temp_buf[1]);
        }
            // dgb_printf_safe("humi: %02d.%02d\r\n", temp_buf[2], temp_buf[3]);
        else
            dgb_printf_safe("get humi failed:%d\r\n", dht11_ret);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

because the parameter passing from app_task_keyboard is 'A', so program will go to case 'A', in case 'A' will use dht11_get_data function
int8_t dht11_get_data(uint8_t *buf)
{
    uint16_t t;
    int8_t i, j,  byte;
    uint8_t *pbuf;
    uint32_t checksum = 0;

    pbuf = buf;

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = DHT11_Pin; //set GPIO pins
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;            //set pin mode, IN/OUT
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;           //set pin speed, higher speed with higher response but higher consumption
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;        //specify pull-up or pull-down
    HAL_GPIO_Init(DHT11_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);                      //init pin

    PGout(9) = 0;
    delay_ms(25);   // 主机至少拉低18ms
    PGout(9) = 1;
    delay_us(30);   // 主机拉高20-40us

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = DHT11_Pin; //set GPIO pins
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;            //set pin mode, IN/OUT
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;           //set pin speed, higher speed with higher response but higher consumption
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;        //specify pull-up or pull-down
    HAL_GPIO_Init(DHT11_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);                      //init pin

    t = 0;
    while (PGin(9))    // 等待DHT响应（低电平）
    {
        t++;
        delay_us(1);
        if(t >= 100)
            return -1;
    }

    t = 0;
    while (PGin(9) == 0)  // DHT响应信号（低电平）80us
    {
        t++;
        delay_us(1);
        if(t >= 100)
            return -2;
    }

    t = 0;
    while (PGin(9))   // DHT拉高80us
    {
        t++;
        delay_us(1);
        if(t >= 100)
            return -3;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        byte = 0;
        for(j = 7; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            t = 0;
            while (PGin(9) == 0)
            {
                t++;
                delay_us(1);
                if(t > 60)
                    return -4;
            }

            delay_us(40);

            if(PGin(9) == 1)
            {
                byte |= (1 << j);

                t = 0;
                while(PGin(9) == 1)
                {
                    t++;
                    delay_us(1);
                    if(t > 60)
                        return -5;
                }
            }
        }
        pbuf[i] = byte;
    }

    checksum = pbuf[0] + pbuf[1] + pbuf[2] + pbuf[3];

    if(checksum != pbuf[4])
        return -6;

    return 1;
}

after got the data from DHT11 module, will print the value through USART to my lab top, and then system will stuck by:
void vPortEnterCritical( void )
{
    portDISABLE_INTERRUPTS();
    uxCriticalNesting++;

    /* This is not the interrupt safe version of the enter critical function so
    assert() if it is being called from an interrupt context.  Only API
    functions that end in "FromISR" can be used in an interrupt.  Only assert if
    the critical nesting count is 1 to protect against recursive calls if the
    assert function also uses a critical section. */
    if( uxCriticalNesting == 1 )
    {
        configASSERT( ( portNVIC_INT_CTRL_REG & portVECTACTIVE_MASK ) == 0 );
    }
}

BUT!!! If I move codes of handle_authenticated_input like below, the system is running smoothly, and you can get any times of temperature or humidity you wanted:
static void app_task_keyboard(void *pvParameter)
{
    int8_t key_val = 0;
    char convertion_val;
    uint8_t temp_buf[4];
    int8_t dht11_ret = 0;

    tft_t tft;

    BaseType_t uxHighWaterMark;

    for(;;)
    {
        key_val = matrix_key_scan();

        // dgb_printf_safe("keyboard\r\n");

        // 判断是否输入正确密码进入系统
        if(authenticated)
        {
            // 开始扫描用户按键，执行相应的功能
            if(key_val >0 && key_val < 17)
            {
                convertion_val = matrix_val_convert(key_val);

                dgb_printf_safe("%c\r\n", convertion_val);

                switch (convertion_val)
                {
                case 'A':
                    // 温度查询
                    dht11_ret = dht11_get_data(temp_buf);
                    if(dht11_ret)
                    {
                        dgb_printf_safe("temp: %02d.%02d\r\n", temp_buf[2], temp_buf[3]);
                    }
                    else
                        dgb_printf_safe("get temp failed:%d\r\n", dht11_ret);
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    // 湿度查询
                    dht11_ret = dht11_get_data(temp_buf);
                    if(dht11_ret)
                    {
                        dgb_printf_safe("humi: %02d.%02d\r\n", temp_buf[0], temp_buf[1]);
                    }
                        // dgb_printf_safe("humi: %02d.%02d\r\n", temp_buf[2], temp_buf[3]);
                    else
                        dgb_printf_safe("get humi failed:%d\r\n", dht11_ret);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }

                // 通过识别到的按键，进行功能选择
                // handle_authenticated_input(convertion_val);
            }
        }

        vTaskDelay(1);
    }
}

The stack of the task should be enough, and when move code into keyboard_task directly instead of nesting function, the program ran well

Can you post the task declaration/create part too?

The comment close to the failing assert is pretty clear. You may be calling a non ISR safe function from an ISR. What does you ISR handle looks like for your dht11?

In such cases, I would recommend using a debugger (gdb). Place a break point at the failing assert and run the gdb build-in command bt. It will provide you with the call stack and may help you go back to the faulty point.

Whenever I've had similar issues (with FreeRTOS on STM32) it has always been because interrupts had too high a priority. PendSV should have the lowest priority. Other interrupts can be higher priority, but if they call (directly or indirectly) any FreeRTOS functions, they must be at least as low as configLIBRARY_MAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY or lower. Which is defined in your FreeRTOSConfig.h file or similar.

Note that on STM32, lower numbers for interrupts are higher priority. 0 is higher priority than 1, for example.
